# How to have CGPath from SKLabelNode?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, cgpath, sklabelnode

How can I extract the polygon path from a `SKLabelNode`? For example I want the edge path of a number like this to move along a `SKSpriteNode`:

[image]

Do you think is possible? Or I must create a polygon for each character like:

```
var pathNumberOne = CGPathCreateMutable()
CGPathMoveToPoint(pathNumberOne , nil, 0, 0)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathNumberOne , nil, 20, 0) 
CGPathAddLineToPoint.....
........
........
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it's to obtain the borders.
The basic idea is to use an `SKShapeNode` to draw the border and add it as a child of your `SKLabelNode`. Something like this:

```
if let path = createBorderPathForText() {
    let border = SKShapeNode()

    border.strokeColor = borderColor
    border.lineWidth = 7;
    border.path = path
    border.position = positionBorder(border)
    labelNode.addChild(border)
}
```

The difficult part is how to create a border for your text. This is where `Core Text` kicks in. With the function `CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters` you retrieve the glyphs for all characters in your text string. For every glyph you can create the `CGPath` using `CTFontCreatePathForGlyph`. The only thing you have to do is add the `CGPath` of all characters together and use this in your `SKShapeNode`. You can do this using the function `CGPathAddPath`. To obtain the relative positions of the glyphs/characters you can use the function `CTFontGetAdvancesForGlyphs`. Putting it all together:

```
private func createBorderPathForText() -> CGPathRef? {
    let chars = getTextAsCharArray()
    let borderFont = CTFontCreateWithName(self.fontName, self.fontSize, nil)

    var glyphs = Array(count: chars.count, repeatedValue: 0)
    let gotGlyphs = CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(borderFont, chars, &glyphs, chars.count)

    if gotGlyphs {
        var advances = Array(count: chars.count, repeatedValue: CGSize())
        CTFontGetAdvancesForGlyphs(borderFont, CTFontOrientation.OrientationHorizontal, glyphs, &advances, chars.count);

        let letters = CGPathCreateMutable()
        var xPosition = 0 as CGFloat
        for index in 0...(chars.count - 1) {
            let letter = CTFontCreatePathForGlyph(borderFont, glyphs[index], nil)
            var t = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(xPosition , 0)
            CGPathAddPath(letters, &t, letter)
            xPosition = xPosition + advances[index].width
        }

        return letters
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

You can find a nice project [here](https://github.com/marioklaver/MKOutlinedLabelNode) on github called **MKOutlinedLabelNode**
 and for more details visit also this [page](http://endpoint.nl/blog/outline-text-in-spritekit) about outline text in spritekit.

Comment: Thanks @Alessandro Ornano , I'll check soon this approach!